# We can suppose without loss... General Dirichlet question

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, dirichlet-series

I would like to know why I can start supposing that $\sigma_{0}=0$ in the proof of the following theorem about Dirichlet series:

***"Let $a_{n}\ge0$ for every $n\ge1$. Then the point $s=\sigma_{0}$ is a singularity of $f$."***

Where $f$ is the Dirichlet series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}$ and $\sigma_{0}$ is the abscissa of convergence.

If needed for more context I can indicate the full proof of the theorem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $f(s)=\sum\frac{a_n}{n^s}$. Define $g(s)=f(s+\sigma_0)$. Then $g(s)=\sum\frac{b_n}{n^s}$ where $b_n=a_n/n^{\sigma_0}\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!